# How do I make my guess function work in my guess the number game?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I am making a guess the number game with HTML, CSS, and javascript. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong with my javascript. I've tried multiple things to make it work, but I can't figure it out. The only button I'm working on right now is the easy game mode. Some of it will work, but the guess button won't work. Here's my code:

```js
function easy() {
  var easyNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<div id='easyDiv'><p>Guess a number between 1 and 5</p><br><input id='easyGuess'><br><br><button id='guess' onclick='guessEasy()'>Guess!</button></div>";
}

function guessEasy() {
  if (document.getElementById('easyDiv').value == easyNum) {
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<h2>That is correct!</h2>";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<h2>That is incorrect.</h2><h2>The number was" + easyNum + ".</h2>";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

#guess {
  padding: 5px;
  border-color: #c3c3c3;
  background: #c3c3c3;
}

input {
  border: 0.5px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  background: #d4d4d4;
}

button {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
  padding: 7.5px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#easy {
  background: #00ff00;
}

#medium {
  background: #ffff00;
}

#hard {
  background: #ff6600;
}

#insane {
  background: #ff0000;
}

#menu {
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-family: arial;
}

#header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
}

#title {
  font-family: arial;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

body {
  background: radial-gradient(#aaaaff, #00003b) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Guess the Number</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1 id="title">Guess the Number</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="menu">
    <u><h2>Level Select</h2></u>
    <br>
    <button id="easy" onclick="easy()"><b>Easy</b></button>
    <button id="medium" onclick="medium()"><b>Medium</b></button>
    <button id="hard" onclick="hard()"><b>Hard</b></button>
    <button id="insane" onclick="insane()"><b>Insane</b></button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope you can help me with this. Thanks! (I just need help with the javascript)

Answer (score 1):

`easyNum` only exists within the function block that it was created in. You either need to make it a global variable so that `guessEasy()` can access it, or pass it as an argument to `guessEasy()` like so:

```
"<div ... onclick='guessEasy(" + easyNum + ")' ...></div>"
```

As for your other difficulty levels, it's up to you to implement the functions `medium()`, `hard()` and `insane()` to get the rest of the game working.

```js
function easy() {
  var easyNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<div id='easyDiv'><p>Guess a number between 1 and 5</p><br><input id='easyGuess'><br><br><button id='guess' onclick='guessEasy("+easyNum +")'>Guess!</button></div>";
}

function guessEasy(easyNum) {
  if (document.getElementById('easyGuess').value == easyNum) { // change to 'easyGuess'
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<h2>That is correct!</h2>";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<h2>That is incorrect.</h2><h2>The number was " + easyNum + ".</h2>";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

#guess {
  padding: 5px;
  border-color: #c3c3c3;
  background: #c3c3c3;
}

input {
  border: 0.5px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  background: #d4d4d4;
}

button {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
  padding: 7.5px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#easy {
  background: #00ff00;
}

#medium {
  background: #ffff00;
}

#hard {
  background: #ff6600;
}

#insane {
  background: #ff0000;
}

#menu {
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-family: arial;
}

#header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
}

#title {
  font-family: arial;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

body {
  background: radial-gradient(#aaaaff, #00003b) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Guess the Number</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1 id="title">Guess the Number</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="menu">
    <u><h2>Level Select</h2></u>
    <br>
    <button id="easy" onclick="easy()"><b>Easy</b></button>
    <button id="medium" onclick="medium()"><b>Medium</b></button>
    <button id="hard" onclick="hard()"><b>Hard</b></button>
    <button id="insane" onclick="insane()"><b>Insane</b></button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @rac0208 this has an issue. check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58279016/12167785

Answer (score 1):

**error 1: You declared the easyNum local to easy().**

**error 2: You were trying to use the div's value (easyDiv).**

```
var easyNum; //change 1

function easy() {
  easyNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<div id='easyDiv'><p>Guess a number between 1 and 5</p><br><input id='easyGuess'><br><br><button id='guess' onclick='guessEasy()'>Guess!</button></div>";
}

function guessEasy() {
  if (document.getElementById('easyGuess').value == easyNum) { //change 2
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<h2>That is correct!</h2>";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<h2>That is incorrect.</h2><h2>The number was" + easyNum + ".</h2>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `var easyNum;` outside of the function so that it can be used globally.

```
var easyNum;

function easy() {
  easyNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<div id='easyDiv'><p>Guess a number between 1 and 5</p><br><input id='easyGuess'><br><br><button id='guess' onclick='guessEasy()'>Guess!</button></div>";
}

function guessEasy() {
  if (document.getElementById('easyDiv').value == easyNum) {
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<h2>That is correct!</h2>";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<h2>That is incorrect.</h2><h2>The number was" + easyNum + ".</h2>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the "easyNum" variable outside of the function. like this:

```js
var easyNum;
function easy() {
  easyNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<div id='easyDiv'><p>Guess a number between 1 and 5</p><br><input id='easyGuess'><br><br><button id='guess' onclick='guessEasy()'>Guess!</button></div>";
}

function guessEasy() {
  if (document.getElementById('easyDiv').value == easyNum) {
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<h2>That is correct!</h2>";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<h2>That is incorrect.</h2><h2>The number was" + easyNum + ".</h2>";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

#guess {
  padding: 5px;
  border-color: #c3c3c3;
  background: #c3c3c3;
}

input {
  border: 0.5px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  background: #d4d4d4;
}

button {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
  padding: 7.5px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#easy {
  background: #00ff00;
}

#medium {
  background: #ffff00;
}

#hard {
  background: #ff6600;
}

#insane {
  background: #ff0000;
}

#menu {
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-family: arial;
}

#header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
}

#title {
  font-family: arial;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

body {
  background: radial-gradient(#aaaaff, #00003b) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Guess the Number</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1 id="title">Guess the Number</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="menu">
    <u><h2>Level Select</h2></u>
    <br>
    <button id="easy" onclick="easy()"><b>Easy</b></button>
    <button id="medium" onclick="medium()"><b>Medium</b></button>
    <button id="hard" onclick="hard()"><b>Hard</b></button>
    <button id="insane" onclick="insane()"><b>Insane</b></button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:

- In your `easyGuess` function you check the easyDiv value, `document.getElementById('easyDiv').value == easyNum`, but actually you want to check the easyGuess value like this: `document.getElementById('easyGuess').value == easyNum`.
- Your variable `easyNum` is scoped to your function `easy`.  For this, you have a few different options:

**Option #1: define `easyNum` outside of your `easy` function:**

```js
var easyNum;

function easy() {
  easyNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<div id='easyDiv'><p>Guess a number between 1 and 5</p><br><input id='easyGuess'><br><br><button id='guess' onclick='guessEasy()'>Guess!</button></div>";
}

function guessEasy() {
  if (document.getElementById('easyGuess').value == easyNum) {
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<h2>That is correct!</h2>";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<h2>That is incorrect.</h2><h2>The number was" + easyNum + ".</h2>";
  }
}
```

**Option #2: call your `easy` function from your `guessEasy` function:**

```js
var easy = function() {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<div id='easyDiv'><p>Guess a number between 1 and 5</p><br><input id='easyGuess'><br><br><button id='guess' onclick='guessEasy()'>Guess!</button></div>";
  return num;
}

function guessEasy() {
  var easyNum = easy();
  if (document.getElementById('easyGuess').value == easyNum) {
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<h2>That is correct!</h2>";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<h2>That is incorrect.</h2><h2>The number was" + easyNum + ".</h2>";
  }
}
```

**Option #3: as another StackOverflow user already suggested here, pass `easyNum` into `guessEasy` as an argument:**

```js
function easy() {
  var easyNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<div id='easyDiv'><p>Guess a number between 1 and 5</p><br><input id='easyGuess'><br><br><button id='guess' onclick='guessEasy("+ easyNum +")'>Guess!</button></div>";
}

function guessEasy(easyNum) {
  if (document.getElementById('easyGuess').value == easyNum) {
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<h2>That is correct!</h2>";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<h2>That is incorrect.</h2><h2>The number was " + easyNum + ".</h2>";
  }
}
```

Comment: @SudhakarRS pointed out that there is another error in the code.  For the sake of completeness I will update this answer.